# Problems with importing package from Github

Tags: clojure, leiningen

before I start, you probably need to know three things:

1. I don't have Java background
2. I'm a Clojure newbie - started to learn it
3. question is related to my "training" package [kennyfy](https://github.com/radmen/clojure-kennyfy/)

**TL;DR version** I'm not able to import/use my training package in a project

**Longer version**
I set myself a goal - write simple API which converts text to kennyspeak. Before that I've created a package (using default lein template).

I tried to import this package to my API.

Part of `project.clj` looks like this:

```clj
:repositories [["jitpack" "https://jitpack.io"]]
:dependencies [[com.github.radmen/clojure-kennyfy "0.1.2"]]
```

`lein deps` fetches the package without any problems.

When I try to use it, Clojure fails with following message:

```
kennyfy-api.core=> (radmen.kennyfy/kenny-speak "foo")

ClassNotFoundException radmen.kennyfy  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:382)
```

I understand the error, yet I've no idea why this class is not imported.
I am quite sure, that this may be related to the metadata stored in the package, which results in failed imports.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_192"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_192-b26)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.192-b26, mixed mode)

$ lein version
Leiningen 2.8.3 on Java 1.8.0_192 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Clojure 1.9.0
```

Comment: `["jitpack" "https://jitpack.io"]` must be `[["jitpack" "https://jitpack.io"]]`

Comment: Works for me, by the way. Try to restart your repl.

Comment: Thanks, @akond. I incorrectly copy-pasted `:repositories` part. In the project, it was set correctly.

Comment: @akond I've tried once again, problem is the same. Maybe it depends on Java/Clojure/Leiningen version? I'll put them in the post.

Comment: Are you `require`ing the `radmen.kennyfy` namespace?

Comment: @Lee tried to use it directly. `require` failed with the same error.

Comment: How are you starting the repl? Have you installed the `clojure-kennyfy` jar locally or is it in some public repository?

Comment: @Lee `lein repl`. It's a public repo, I'm using Jitpack to fetch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clojure namespaces is loaded the first time it is required.

```
foo.core=> (radmen.kennyfy/kenny-speak "foo")

Execution error (ClassNotFoundException) at java.net.URLClassLoader/findClass (URLClassLoader.java:382).
radmen.kennyfy
foo.core=> (require '[radmen.kennyfy :as kennyfy])
nil
foo.core=> (kennyfy/kenny-speak "foo")
"mpfppfppf"
foo.core=> (radmen.kennyfy/kenny-speak "foo")
"mpfppfppf"
foo.core=>
```